# How to find domain of convergence and sum for such series: $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}} $$
Given that $1+x^{4n}$>x^{4n} take a series  $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^{2n}}{x^{4n}} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{x^{2n}}$, then for $|x| > 1 \ \ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{x^{2n}} \in R \Rightarrow \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}} \in R$

I was told that this is not a solution, because I haven't found neither the domain of convergence nor sum of the series. But if it converges given that $|x|>1 $, then isn't it also a domain of convergence?

Here I try to find sum:

$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}+\frac{x^4}{1+x^8}+ \frac{x^6}{1+x^{12}}+... +\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}}+...$$

What can I do with it, to try and determine the sum for the series?

Here is my try using ratio test:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{x^{2n+2}(1+x^{4n})}{(1+x^{4n+4})x^{2n}}  \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{x^2(1+x^{4n})}{1+x^{4n+4}} \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{1+x^{4n}}{\frac{1}{x^2}+x^{4n+2}} \right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{1}{x^{4n}}+1}{\frac{1}{x^{4n+2}}+x^2}\right| = \frac{1}{x^2}$$
For $|x|>1 $ series converge. For $x=1$: $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \text{series diverge, because }p\le 1$ . If $x= -1,$ then: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{1+(-1)^{4n}} =\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \text{ series diverge.} $$
So the domain of series: $x\in ]-\infty, 1[ \cup ]1, \infty[$

Comment: Try the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), perhaps?

Comment: Try cases, $|x|>1$, $|x|<1$, $|x|=1$ since all you've proven is that you've found a subset of the domain of convergence. For your work $|x|<1$ diverging doesn't prove anything because your series is less than a diverging one

Comment: @NinadMunshi Here I tried to find the domain using ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

For $ x=0 $, it converges.

If $ x^2>1,$

When $ n\to +\infty$,

$$\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}}\sim \frac{x^{2n}}{x^{4n}}=(\frac{1}{x^2})^n$$

the series converges.

If $ x^2<1$,
$$\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}}\sim x^{2n}$$

the series converges.

If $ x^2=1,$
$$\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}}=\frac 12$$
the series diverges.

The domaine of convergence is then
$$(-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $|x| > 1$ (and $x$ is real), then you do have $0 < \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}} \le \frac{1}{x^{2n}}$ implying convergence.  On the other hand, if $|x| < 1$ you have
$ 0 \le \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}} \le x^{2n}$, again implying convergence.
Only for $|x|=1$ do you not have convergence.

You're not going to get a closed-form formula for the sum.
For $|x| < 1$ it can be rewritten as
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^{2(2k+1)n}
  = \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m) x^{2m} $$
where $f(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$ congruent to $1 (\mod 4)$ minus the number of divisors of $m$ congruent to $3 (\mod 4)$.

Similarly, for $|x|>1$ it is $\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m) x^{-2m}$.

Note that since $$ \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}} = \frac{x^{-2n}}{x^{-4n}+1}$$
the sum at $x$ and $1/x$ are equal.

Comment: For coefficients, see http://oeis.org/A002654